# Workaround with 'Column Name is not valid'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-ce

Hi is there any workaround with this one?

```
SELECT        invoices.no, customers.name, invoices.mdcode,
SUM(iproducts.unitprice * iproducts.quantity) AS total,
SUM(iproducts.unitprice * iproducts.quantity) - SUM(rinvoices.payment + rinvoices.discount)
AS [Remaining Balance]
FROM          invoices INNER JOIN
              customers ON customers.id = invoices.customerid INNER JOIN
              iproducts ON invoices.id = iproducts.invoiceid LEFT OUTER JOIN
              rinvoices ON invoices.id = rinvoices.invoiceid
WHERE        ([Remaining Balance] <> '0')
GROUP BY invoices.no, customers.name, invoices.mdcode
```

The following returns an error that '[Remaining Balance]' is not a valid column whereas i already declared it. i can't use it in both the WHERE and the CASE clauses. Is there any work around since i really need to get only the invoices that have still remaining balances.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @AVD - no, its about filtering on aggregate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use HAVING clause like this

```
HAVING SUM(rinvoices.payment) - SUM(rinvoices.discount) <> 0
```

instead of WHERE

Ie:

```
SELECT        invoices.no, customers.name, invoices.mdcode,
SUM(iproducts.unitprice * iproducts.quantity) AS total,
SUM(iproducts.unitprice * iproducts.quantity) - SUM(rinvoices.payment + rinvoices.discount)
AS [Remaining Balance]
FROM          invoices INNER JOIN
              customers ON customers.id = invoices.customerid INNER JOIN
              iproducts ON invoices.id = iproducts.invoiceid LEFT OUTER JOIN
              rinvoices ON invoices.id = rinvoices.invoiceid
GROUP BY invoices.no, customers.name, invoices.mdcode
HAVING SUM(rinvoices.payment) - SUM(rinvoices.discount) <> 0
```

Comment: Hey Thanks! wow it worked! and you guys reply so fast! thanks A LOT and you guys are great!

Comment: This is the StackOverflow. It is fast 8-) And you may accept an answer if liked it

Comment: yeah, i'm waiting for the 6 mins gap before stackoverflow allows me to. :)