# How to omit System Databases using SMO in For Next

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

Having read a reply post by Chris Diver, I found the SMO "list Databases" very useful. Here is the code:

```
For Each db As Database In server.Databases
    Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(db.Name)
Next
```

The above code lists all Databases on SQL Server 2008 R2. I would like to omit System Databases from the above code results.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the database. Don't add if its system db.
Here is a piece of code for this

```
Dim value As Boolean

For Each db As Database In server.Databases
    value = db .IsSystemObject
    if NOT value  Then
        Me.ComboBox1.Items.Add(db.Name)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Commendable! The 2 reportserver db's display on the combo. Other than that the combo list is shortened. Great!

Comment: Geek, How do I mark as answered? Should I type in a comment like the way I am typing these lines? or is there an marking option? Today is my first day blogging at stackoverflow, pls excuse me.

Comment: There must be a tick mark appearing on the left side of my answer. Just check it. you can see it in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815240/workaround-with-column-name-is-not-valid

Comment: Done! By the way could you check my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817040/how-to-display-a-login-failure-messagebox-for-app-config-connection-string. Appreciate if you could look at this thread. Tks!